# Subfolder gitignore not un-ignoring files ignored by parent gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

First let me say that this is not my project, I'm pulled into it, and I'm not supportive of ignore all.... That said, this is where I stand...

Root of the repo has the following `.gitignore`

```bash
#########
#Exclude all
#########
################# many other project specific files unignored*****
*
!*/
!.gitignore
#########
#C-Sharp-files
#########
!*.cs
!*.csproj
!*.sln
!*.resx
!*.config
!*.ico
!*.settings
!*.exe
!*.dll
!*.ld
```

and in a subfolder `alpha/test_gui/gui_source` there is a `bin` folder. within the `test_gui` folder I have another `.gitignore` file that that has the following line

```bash
[Bb]in/
```

I do want to ignore this folder, however, within the `bin` folder, there is a `scripts` folder I want to commit to source. the only way I can get this to work is by adding the following to the root `.gitignore`

```bash
# ./.gitignore
!alpha/test_gui/gui_source/bin/scripts/*
```

and the following to the `.gitignore in` alpha/test_gui/gui_source`

```bash
# ./alpha/test_gui/gui_source/.gitignore
![Bb]in/
[Bb]in/*
![Bb]in/scripts/*
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring a folder means never checking its contents at all. No paths within it will be checked. You don't want that. You don't want to summarily ignore the `alpha/test_gui/gui_source/bin` folder, you do want to check some of its contents.

In `alpha/test_gui/gui_source/.gitignore`:

```
bin/**
!bin/scripts/**
# and at the bottom:
!*/
```

Unless you're really really sure there are directories you want to completely ignore the easiest to understand  is to use that `dir/**` pattern and put `!*/` at the bottom of every `.gitignore`; then any directories you really truly do want to ignore completely, maybe because scanning them is getting annoyingly slow, list those *after* the `!*/` so they'll be the ["last matching pattern"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description) in that `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems this doesn't work with the `./.gitignore` parent patterns that I am faced with. Is there a solution that works just by modifying the `alpha/test_gui/.gitignore`?

Comment: My fault, I got lost in the prose description of your directory structure.  I think I fixed all the names right.